# .EACHI in data.table?

Tags: r, performance, group-by, data.table

I cannot seem to find any documentation on what exactly `.EACHI` does in `data.table`. I see a brief mention of it in the documentation:

> Aggregation for a subset of known groups is particularly efficient
>   when passing those groups in i and setting `by=.EACHI`. When `i` is a
>   data.table, `DT[i,j,by=.EACHI]` evaluates `j` for the groups of `DT` that
>   each row in `i` joins to. We call this grouping by each i.

But what does "groups" in the context of `DT` mean? Is a group determined by the key that is set on `DT`? Is the group every distinct row that uses all the columns as the key? I fully understand how to run something like `DT[i,j,by=my_grouping_variable]` but am confused as to how `.EACHI` would work. Could someone explain please?

Comment: thanks for point out. unfortunately the link in the answer doesn't work and nothing else in the answer talks about `.EACHI`

Comment: Actually, @eddi's answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25869543/how-to-count-occurrences-combinations-in-data-table-in-r/25872206#25872206 might provide a bit of insight

Comment: i see: so according to that `.EACHI` defines groups based on the way the merge between `i` and `DT` occurs. that is, if `i` uses a key for merging that key defines the groups for `DT`. in other words, each row in `i` represents a group (along with the returned rows of `DT`). would be good if package owner could confirm. and in that case, is that fasted then specifying a `by=` condition?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

I've added this to the list [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/944). And hopefully we'll be able to deliver as planned.

---

The reason is most likely that `by=.EACHI` is a recent feature (since 1.9.4), *but what it does isn't*. Let me explain with an example. Suppose we have two data.tables `X` and `Y`:

```
X = data.table(x = c(1,1,1,2,2,5,6), y = 1:7, key = "x")
Y = data.table(x = c(2,6), z = letters[2:1], key = "x")
```

We know that we can join by doing `X[Y]`. this is similar to a *subset* operation, but using `data.tables` (instead of integers / row names or logical values). For each row in `Y`, taking `Y`'s key columns, it finds and returns corresponding matching rows in `X`'s key columns (+ columns in `Y`) .

```
X[Y]
#    x y z
# 1: 2 4 b
# 2: 2 5 b
# 3: 6 7 a
```

Now let's say we'd like to, for each row from `Y`'s key columns (here only one key column), we'd like to get the *count* of matches in `X`. In versions of `data.table` **< 1.9.4**, we can do this by simply specifying `.N` in `j` as follows:

```
# < 1.9.4
X[Y, .N]
#    x N
# 1: 2 2
# 2: 6 1
```

What this *implicitly* does is, in the presence of `j`, evaluate the `j-expression` on each matched result of `X` (corresponding to the row in `Y`). This was called *by-without-by* or *implicit-by*, because it's as if there's a hidden by.

The issue was that this'll always perform a `by` operation. So, if we wanted to know the number of rows after a join, then we'd have to do: `X[Y][ .N]` (or simply `nrow(X[Y])` in this case). That is, we can't have the `j` expression in the same call if we don't want a `by-without-by`. As a result, when we did for example `X[Y, list(z)]`, it evaluated `list(z)` using `by-without-by` and was therefore slightly slower.

Additionally `data.table` users requested this to be *explicit* - see [this](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/371) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16093289/data-table-join-and-j-expression-unexpected-behavior/) for more context.

Hence `by=.EACHI` was added. Now, when we do:

```
X[Y, .N]
# [1] 3
```

it does what it's meant to do (avoids confusion). It returns the number of rows resulting from the join.

And,

```
X[Y, .N, by=.EACHI]
```

evaluates `j`-expression on the matching rows for each row in `Y` (corresponding to value from `Y`'s key columns here). It'd be easier to see this by using `which=TRUE`.

```
X[.(2), which=TRUE] # [1] 4 5
X[.(6), which=TRUE] # [1] 7
```

If we run `.N` for each, then we should get 2,1.

```
X[Y, .N, by=.EACHI]
#    x N
# 1: 2 2
# 2: 6 1
```

So we now have both functionalities.

Comment: boom! what an answer. thanks for this, it's very helpful. if i can make a suggestion, put this somewhere on the documentation in big block letters in bold. i, for one, always used the `X[Y][,j]` syntax or `X[Y][,j,by=my_var]` so this marks an important change that might confuse some folks like me

Comment: Thanks. Linking to this Q in the next release (1.9.6) might be a good idea, until vignettes are out. Will do.

Comment: I do not know if it was chance, but this way:  `X[Y, .N, by = x]` I get the same result