# speeding up a data.table cartesian product with filtering

Tags: r, data.table

Given a `data.table` with three fields `member_id`, `provider_id` and `srvc_dt`.  I need to compute the number of distinct members seen by a pair of providers.  A member is said to have visited two providers if the visits have occurred within 180 days. This is used to construct an undirected graph using a threshold for #visits and look for connected components.

I am using the method suggested in [Cartesian product with filter data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27059924/cartesian-product-with-filter-data-table).

The instance that I need to run has over 3 million records and it is taking over 5 mins to run.  Is there a way of re-writing or a new data.table function so that it runs faster?

```
require(data.table)

nmem <- 5000
data.dt <- data.table(member_id=sample(10000:1000000,nmem,replace=TRUE), provider_id=sample(1000:2000,nmem,replace=TRUE),
    srvc_dt=sample(seq(as.Date('2014/01/01'), as.Date('2015/01/01'), by="day"), nmem, replace=TRUE))
setkey(data.dt, member_id)

prov_pair.dt <- data.dt[data.dt, {
        idx = provider_id<i.provider_id & abs(srvc_dt-i.srvc_dt)<180
        list(provider_id1 = provider_id[idx], 
            srvc_dt1 = srvc_dt[idx],
            provider_id2 = i.provider_id[any(idx)],
            srvc_dt2 = i.srvc_dt[any(idx)]
        )
    }, by=.EACHI, allow=TRUE]

prov_pair_agg.dt <- prov_pair.dt[, .(weight=length(unique(member_id))), .(provider_id1,provider_id2)]
```

Answer (score 2):

simple left-join followed by filtering:

```
prov_pair.dt <- data.dt[data.dt,allow.cartesian=T][provider_id<i.provider_id &
  abs(srvc_dt-i.srvc_dt)<180,]
```

`provider_id<i.provider_id` prevents double-counting the same visits to x,y and y,x.

also, now use `provider_id` and `i.provider_id` instead of `provider_id1` and `provider_id2` in computing `prov_pair_agg.dt`:

```
prov_pair_agg.dt <- prov_pair.dt[, .(weight=length(unique(member_id))), 
  .(provider_id,i.provider_id)]
```

on a 16gb memory machine with nmem=1,000,000, this takes 1.487s vs 106.034s by your current method.

Comment: please set nmem to 1000000 and try.  I am getting the following error `...Join results in 2009362 rows; more than 2000000 = nrow(x)+nrow(i)...`.  The advantage with the other approach is that it is memory efficient (see the last line in @Arun's post).

Comment: with nmem=1,000,000, `allow.cartesian=T` is required, but this way is still fast, provided sufficient memory.

Comment: perhaps filtering out members who only saw a single provider, i.e. starting with `data.dt[, if (.N >= 2) .SD, by = member_id]`, will solve memory issues (depends on data of course)

Comment: @webb thanks.  Unfortunately, the memory spikes suddenly right after I kick this off and I am out of memory.  I do see that this is MUCH faster for smaller instances.

Comment: @eddi  thanks.  I had filtered those out up front in my code.

Answer (score 0):

First, filter out the data to only include members that have seen more than one provider:

```
res = data.dt[, if (.N >= 2) .SD, by = member_id]
```

Then, add the endpoints for the dates, and a copy of the provider column:

```
res[, `:=`(start.date = srvc_dt - 180,
           end.date   = srvc_dt + 180,
           provider2  = provider_id)]
```

Finally, use the new non-equi joins, available in the [development version](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation):

```
res[res, on = .(member_id = member_id, provider2 < provider_id,
                srvc_dt < end.date, srvc_dt > start.date)
    , allow = T, nomatch = 0][, .N, by = .(provider1 = provider_id, provider2)]
```

One note - the names of the columns in the above join are currently unfortunately a little confusing, and hopefully that will get sorted out soon. You can add extra copies of the columns to see what exactly is going on if the above is too unclear.