# Find the minimum distance between two data frames, for each element in the second data frame

Tags: r, plyr, dplyr

I have two data frames ev1 and ev2, describing timestamps of two types of events collected over many tests. So, each data frame has columns "test_id", and "timestamp". What I need to find is the minimum distance of ev1 for each ev2, in the same test.

I have a working code that merges the two datasets, calculates the distances, and then uses dplyr to filter for the minimum distance:

```
ev1 = data.frame(test_id = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), time=c(1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4))
ev2 = data.frame(test_id = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), time=c(6, 1, 8, 4, 5, 11))

data <- merge(ev2, ev1, by=c("test_id"), suffixes=c(".ev2", ".ev1"))

data$distance <- data$time.ev2 - data$time.ev1

min_data <- data %>%
  group_by(test_id, time.ev2) %>%
  filter(abs(distance) == min(abs(distance)))
```

While this works, the merge part is very slow and feels inefficient -- I'm generating a huge table with all combinations of ev2->ev1 for the same test_id, only to filter it down to one. It seems like there should be a way to "filter on the fly", during the merge. Is there?

**Update**: The following case with two "group by" columns fails when data.table approach outlined by akrun is used:

```
ev1 = data.frame(test_id = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), time=c(1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4), group_id=c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1))
ev2 = data.frame(test_id = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), time=c(5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 8), group_id=c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1))
setkey(setDT(ev1), test_id, group_id)
DT <- ev1[ev2, allow.cartesian=TRUE][,distance:=abs(time-i.time)]
```

*Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'i.time' not found*

Comment: have you tried `left_join(ev2,ev1, by=c("test_id") )` instead of `merge`?

Comment: @Khashaa No, I didn't. I tried it now, and it's infinitely faster. Is it just a much better implementation of the same thing, or is something else going on?

Comment: @Stan Have you tried the `data.table` approach.  It should be very fast.

Comment: @Stan It is the `dplyr` analogue of `merge(., all.x=TRUE)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it using `data.table`:

```
require(data.table)
setkey(setDT(ev1), test_id)
ev1[ev2, .(ev2.time = i.time, ev1.time = time[which.min(abs(i.time - time))]), by = .EACHI]
#    test_id ev2.time ev1.time
# 1:       0        6        3
# 2:       0        1        1
# 3:       0        8        3
# 4:       1        4        4
# 5:       1        5        4
# 6:       1       11        4
```

In joins of the form `x[i]` in `data.table`, the prefix `i.` is used to refer the columns in `i`, when both `x` and `i` share the same name for a particular column.

Please see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27004566/559784) for an explanation on how this works.

This is syntactically more straightforward to understand what's going on, and is memory efficient (at the expense of little speed<sup>1</sup>) as it doesn't materialise the entire join result at all. In fact, this does exactly what you say in your post - *filter on the fly, while merging*.

1. On speed, it doesn't matter in most of the cases really. If there are *a lot* of rows in `i`, it *might* be a tad slower as the `j`-expression will have to be evaluated for each row in `i`. In contrast, @akrun's answer does a cartesian join followed by one filtering. So while it's high on memory, it doesn't evaluate `j` for each row in `i`. But again, this shouldn't even matter unless you work with *really large* `i` which is not often the case.

HTH

Comment: This is perfect -- like you say, exactly what I was hoping to find, something that doesn't create the huge join to begin with. When you say 'at the expense of little speed', what do you mean? What makes this a bit slower than creating the full join and then filtering? On my big testcase, it seemed to be even a little bit faster.

Comment: @Stan, awesome! Glad to hear it helped. Edited to clarify your Q in the post.

Answer (score 0):

May be this helps:

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(ev1), test_id)
DT <- ev1[ev2, allow.cartesian=TRUE][,distance:=time-i.time]
DT[DT[,abs(distance)==min(abs(distance)), by=list(test_id, i.time)]$V1]
#    test_id time i.time distance
#1:       0    3      6        3
#2:       0    1      1        0
#3:       0    3      8        5
#4:       1    4      4        0
#5:       1    4      5        1
#6:       1    4     11        7
```

Or

```
 ev1[ev2, allow.cartesian=TRUE][,distance:= time-i.time][,
      .SD[abs(distance)==min(abs(distance))], by=list(test_id, i.time)]
```

#### Update

Using the new grouping

```
setkey(setDT(ev1), test_id, group_id)
setkey(setDT(ev2), test_id, group_id)
DT <- ev1[ev2, allow.cartesian=TRUE][,distance:=i.time-time]
DT[DT[,abs(distance)==min(abs(distance)), by=list(test_id, 
                                group_id,i.time)]$V1]$distance
#[1]  2  3  4 -1  0  4
```

Based on the code you provided

```
min_data$distance
#[1]  2  3  4 -1  0  4
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with data.table, so I'm going to have to look at this more closely to understand it :). One thing I had to change is to move abs() to the second line - abs(distance) == min(abs(distance)), so that I can still get negative distances (i.e. ev2 happened after ev1).

Comment: One question -- my real-life example had two columns (let's call them test_id and group_id) that together formed the grouping key. How would I change the code above to make that happen? I tried setkey(setDT(ev1), test_id, group_id), which went through, but then I got an error on the next line that object 'i.time' is not found, which puzzled me.

Comment: @Stan Yes, you can move that to the second line.  I was only looking at the `min_data` as reference.  Could you show an example that gives the error (makes it easier to look)?

Comment: I have added an update with an example that gives me the error.

Comment: @Stan You can use `setkey(setDT(ev2), test_id, group_id)` and then try the steps with `by=list(test_id, group_id, i.time)]`

Comment: I don't get that far, though, the error happens on the "DT <- ... " line. After a bit of experimenting, the order of columns seems to matter. If group_id right after test_id, then your code works. If it's at the end (as in the example above), then it doesn't.

Comment: @Stan Please show an example that mimics your dataset.  From testing the code with the code that you showed, it is giving the same result.

Comment: @Stan I tried both ways and it works `setkey(setDT(ev1), group_id, test_id); setkey(setDT(ev2), group_id, test_id); ev1[ev2, allow.cartesian=TRUE][,distance:=i.time-time][]
    test_id time group_id i.time distance
 1:       0    1        0      5        4
 2:       0    2        0      5        3`

Comment: I didn't have the 'setkey(setDT(ev2))' line when I was testing -- it wasn't there in your first example. However, once I've put it in, the code does work, and it is very fast. Thank you!