# drop levels of factor for which there is one missing value for one column r

Tags: r

I would like to drop any occurrence of a factor level for which one row contains a missing value

Example:

```
ID var1 var2
1  1    2
1  NA   3
2  1    2
2  2    4
```

So, in this hypothetical, what would be left would be:

```
ID var1 var2
2  1    2
2  2    4
```

Answer (score 4):

Hers's possible `data.table` solution (sorry @rawr)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, if (all(!is.na(.SD))) .SD, ID]
#    ID var1 var2
# 1:  2    1    2
# 2:  2    2    4
```

If you only want to check `var1` then

```
df[, if (all(!is.na(var1))) .SD, ID]
#    ID var1 var2
# 1:  2    1    2
# 2:  2    2    4
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `NAs` would occur in both `var` columns,

```
 df[with(df, !ave(!!rowSums(is.na(df[,-1])), ID, FUN=any)),]
 #   ID var1 var2
 #3  2    1    2
 #4  2    2    4
```

Or if it is only specific to `var1`

```
 df[with(df, !ave(is.na(var1), ID, FUN=any)),]
 #  ID var1 var2
 #3  2    1    2
 #4  2    2    4
```

Or using `dplyr`

```
 library(dplyr)
 df %>% 
     group_by(ID) %>%
     filter(all(!is.na(var1)))
 #   ID var1 var2
 #1  2    1    2
 #2  2    2    4
```

#### data

```
 df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), var1 = c(1L, NA, 1L, 2L
 ), var2 = c(2L, 3L, 2L, 4L)), .Names = c("ID", "var1", "var2"
 ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one more option in base R. It will check all columns for NAs.

```
df[!df$ID %in% df$ID[rowSums(is.na(df)) > 0],]
#  ID var1 var2
#3  2    1    2
#4  2    2    4
```

If you only want to check in column "var1" you can do:

```
df[!with(df, ID %in% ID[is.na(var1)]),]
#  ID var1 var2
#3  2    1    2
#4  2    2    4
```

Answer (score 2):

In the current development version of `data.table`, there's a new implementation of `na.omit` for data.tables, which takes a `cols =`and `invert =` arguments.

The `cols =` allows to specify the columns on which to look for `NAs`. And `invert = TRUE` returns the NA rows instead, instead of *omitting them*.

You can install the devel version [by following these instructions](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation). Or you can wait for 1.9.6 on CRAN at some point. Using that, we can do:

```
require(data.table) ## 1.9.5+
setkey(setDT(df), ID)
df[!na.omit(df, invert = TRUE)]
#    ID var1 var2
# 1:  2    1    2
# 2:  2    2    4
```

---

How this works:

- `setDT` converts data.frame to data.table by reference.
- `setkey` sorts the data.table by the columns provided and marks those columns as *key columns* so that we can perform a join.
- `na.omit(df, invert = TRUE)` gives just those rows that have `NA` anywhere.
- `X[!Y]` does an anit-join by joining on the key column `ID`, and returns all the rows that don't match `ID = 1` (from `Y`). Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27543075/559784) to read in detail about data.table's joins.

HTH