# Function for pasting corrected values inside existing dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

Does something like the 'paste_over' function below already exist within base R or one of the standard R packages?

```
paste_over <- function(original, corrected, key){
  corrected <- corrected[order(corrected[[key]]),]

  output <- original
  output[
    original[[key]] %in% corrected[[key]],
    names(corrected)
    ] <- corrected

  return(output)
}
```

An example:

```
D1 <- data.frame(
  k = 1:5,
  A = runif(5),
  B = runif(5),
  C = runif(5),
  D = runif(5),
  E = runif(5)
  )

D2 <- data.frame(
  k=c(4,1,3),
  D=runif(3),
  E=runif(3),
  A=runif(3)
  )

D2 <- D2[order(D2$k),]

D3 <- D1
D3[
  D1$k %in% D2$k,
  names(D2)
  ] <- D2


D4 <- paste_over(D1, D2, "k")

all(D4==D3)
```

In the example D2 contains some values that I want to paste over corresponding cells within D1. However D2 is not in the same order and does not have the same dimension as D1.

The motivation for this is that I was given a very large dataset, reported some errors within it, and received a subset of the original dataset with some corrected values. I would like to be able to 'paste over' the new, corrected values into the old dataset without changing the old dataset in terms of structure. (As the rest of the code I've written assume's the old dataset's structure.)

Although the paste_over function seems to work I can't help but think this must have been tackled before, and so maybe there's already a well known function that's both faster and has error checking. If there is then please let me know what it is. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can accomplish this using `data.table` as follows:

```
setkeyv(setDT(D1), "k")
cols = c("D", "E", "A")
D1[D2, (cols) := D2[, cols]]
```

- `setDT()` converts a data.frame to data.table *by reference* (without actually copying the data). We want `D1` to be a data.table.
- `setkey()` sorts the data.table by the column specified (here `k`) and marks that column as *sorted* (by setting the attribute *sorted*) *by reference*. This allows us to perform joins using binary search.
- `x[i]` in data.table performs a join. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27543075/559784). Briefly, for each row of column `k` in `D2`, it finds the matching row indices in `D1` by matching on `D1`'s key column (here `k`).
- `x[i, LHS := RHS]` performs the join to find matching rows, and the `LHS := RHS` part *adds/updates* `x` with the columns specified in `LHS` with the values specified in `RHS` *by reference*. `LHS` should be a a vector of column names or numbers, and `RHS` should be a list of values.

  So, `D1[D2, (cols) := D2[, cols]]` finds matching rows in `D1` for `k=c(1,3,4)` from `D2` and updates the columns `D,E,A` specified in `cols` by the list (a data.frame is also a list) of corresponding columns from `D2` on `RHS`.

`D1` will now be modified *in-place*.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

You could use the replacement method for data frames in your function, like this maybe. It does adequate checking for you. I chose to pass the logical row subset as an argument, but you can change that

```
pasteOver <- function(original, corrected, key) {
    "[<-.data.frame"(original, key, names(corrected), corrected)
}

(p1 <- pasteOver(D1, D2, D1$k %in% D2$k))
  k          A           B         C         D          E
1 1 0.18827167 0.006275082 0.3754535 0.8690591 0.73774065
2 2 0.54335829 0.122160101 0.6213813 0.9931259 0.38941407
3 3 0.62946977 0.323090601 0.4464805 0.5069766 0.41443988
4 4 0.66155954 0.201218532 0.1345516 0.2990733 0.05296677
5 5 0.09400961 0.087096652 0.2327039 0.7268058 0.63687025

p2 <- paste_over(D1, D2, "k")
identical(p1, p2)
# [1] TRUE
```