# Creating variable in R data frame depending on another data frame

Tags: r

I am seeking help after having wasted almost a day. I have a big data frame (bdf) and a small data frame (sdf). I want to add variable z to bdf depending on the value of sdf$y (which changes as a function of a time variable).

Here is a reproducible example:

```
bdf <- data.frame(tb = seq(as.POSIXct("2013-05-19 17:11:22 GMT", tz="GMT"), by=5624*24, length.out=10))

bdf
                tb
1  2013-05-19 17:11:22
2  2013-05-21 06:40:58
3  2013-05-22 20:10:34
4  2013-05-24 09:40:10
5  2013-05-25 23:09:46
6  2013-05-27 12:39:22
7  2013-05-29 02:08:58
8  2013-05-30 15:38:34
9  2013-06-01 05:08:10
10 2013-06-02 18:37:46


sdf <- data.frame(ts = as.POSIXct(c("2013-05-22", "2013-05-25", "2013-05-30"), tz="GMT"), y = c(0.2, -0.1, 0.3))

> sdf
      ts    y
1 2013-05-22  0.2
2 2013-05-25 -0.1
3 2013-05-30  0.3
```

I want to create variable z in bdf with the following values of sdf$y:

- 0.2 for rows where bdf$tb ranges from the first bdf$tb value to mid-way between the 1st and 2nd value of sdf$ts. In this simple example, that is the case of rows 1 to 3 of dbf which have times bdf$tb below "2013-05-23 12:00:00 GMT".
- -0.1 for rows where bdf$tb ranges from mid-way between the 1st and 2nd value of sdf$ts to mid-way between the 2nd and 3rd value of sdf$ts. In this simple example, that is the case of rows 4 and 5 of dbf which have times bdf$tb between "2013-05-23 12:00:00 GMT" and "2013-05-27 12:00:00 GMT".
- 0.3 for all rows where bdf$tb ranges from mid-way between the 2nd and 3rd value of sdf$ts to the last value of bdf$tb. In this simple example, that is the case of rows 1 to 6 to 10 of dbf which have times larger than "2013-05-23 12:00:00 GMT".

Hence, in the end, the big dataframe bdf should look like this:

```
                 tb    z
1  2013-05-19 17:11:22  0.2
2  2013-05-21 06:40:58  0.2
3  2013-05-22 20:10:34  0.2
4  2013-05-24 09:40:10 -0.1
5  2013-05-25 23:09:46 -0.1
6  2013-05-27 12:39:22  0.3
7  2013-05-29 02:08:58  0.3
8  2013-05-30 15:38:34  0.3
9  2013-06-01 05:08:10  0.3
10 2013-06-02 18:37:46  0.3
```

I could not succeed using dplyr::mutate and got nowhere using loops... Any help would be much appreciated. I hope that I clearly described the issue as adhered to the etiquette (it is my first question).

Comment: sounds like _join to nearest value_ In package `data.table` perhaps `roll = "nearest"` but I have no experience in it and  I am curious if it is possible in `dplyr`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems now absolutely unnecessary, but in base `R`

```
bdf$z <- numeric(nrow(bdf))
for(i in seq_along(bdf$z)){
  ind <- which.min(abs(bdf$tb[i] - sdf$ts))
  bdf$z[i] <- sdf$y[ind]
}
```

While being little clumsy, it has an advantage in clarity, which accomodates easy adaptation to `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
bdf %>% rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(z= sdf$y[which.min(abs(as.numeric(tb)-as.numeric(sdf$ts)))])

#Source: local data frame [10 x 2]
#Groups: <by row>

#                    tb    z
#1  2013-05-19 17:11:22  0.2
#2  2013-05-21 06:40:58  0.2
#3  2013-05-22 20:10:34  0.2
#4  2013-05-24 09:40:10 -0.1
#5  2013-05-25 23:09:46 -0.1
#6  2013-05-27 12:39:22  0.3
#7  2013-05-29 02:08:58  0.3
#8  2013-05-30 15:38:34  0.3
#9  2013-06-01 05:08:10  0.3
#10 2013-06-02 18:37:46  0.3
```

Comment: The second option is my favorite. It is the simplest solution as it does not require any additional package and is very short.

Comment: Misunderstood the voting system and want to vote this reply up

Answer (score 9):

Here's a solution using `data.table`'s *rolling joins*:

```
require(data.table)
setkey(setDT(sdf), ts)
sdf[bdf, roll = "nearest"]
#                      ts    y
#  1: 2013-05-19 17:11:22  0.2
#  2: 2013-05-21 06:40:58  0.2
#  3: 2013-05-22 20:10:34  0.2
#  4: 2013-05-24 09:40:10 -0.1
#  5: 2013-05-25 23:09:46 -0.1
#  6: 2013-05-27 12:39:22  0.3
#  7: 2013-05-29 02:08:58  0.3
#  8: 2013-05-30 15:38:34  0.3
#  9: 2013-06-01 05:08:10  0.3
# 10: 2013-06-02 18:37:46  0.3
```

- `setDT` converts data.frame to data.table *by reference*.
- `setkey` sorts the data.table *by reference* in increasing order by the columns provided, and marks those columns as *key columns* (so that we can join on those key columns later.
- In data.table, `x[i]` performs a join when `i` is a data.table. I'll refer you to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27543075/559784) to catch up on data.table joins, if you're not already familiar with.
- `x[i]` performs an *equi-join*. That is, it finds matching row indices in `x` for every row in `i` and then extracts those rows from `x` to return the join result along with the corresponding row from `i`. In case a row in `i` doesn't find matching row indices in `x`, that row would have `NA` for `x` by default.

  However, `x[i, roll = .]` performs a *rolling join*. When there's no match, either the last observation is carried forward (`roll = TRUE` or `-Inf`), or the next observation can be carried backward (`roll = Inf`), or rolled to the nearest value (`roll = "nearest"`). And in this case you require `roll = "nearest"` IIUC.

HTH

Answer (score 3):

Here's my approach:

```
library(zoo)
m <- c(rollmean(as.POSIXct(sdf$ts), 2), Inf)
transform(bdf, z = sdf$y[sapply(tb, function(x) which.max(x < m))])
#                    tb    z
#1  2013-05-19 17:11:22  0.2
#2  2013-05-21 06:40:58  0.2
#3  2013-05-22 20:10:34  0.2
#4  2013-05-24 09:40:10 -0.1
#5  2013-05-25 23:09:46 -0.1
#6  2013-05-27 12:39:22  0.3
#7  2013-05-29 02:08:58  0.3
#8  2013-05-30 15:38:34  0.3
#9  2013-06-01 05:08:10  0.3
#10 2013-06-02 18:37:46  0.3
```

Update: removed conversion to numeric (not required)

Brief explanation:

- `as.POSIXct(sdf$ts)` converts the dates to POSIXct-style date-times
- `rollmean(as.POSIXct(sdf$ts), 2)` computes the rolling mean of each two consecutive rows. This happens to be exactly the time you want to use for separating the observations. `rollmean` is from package `zoo`. Computing a `rollmean(..,2)` means the output vector is shortened by 1 compared to the input vector.
- That is why I wrap the result of `rollmean` in `c(.., Inf)` which means that the infinity value is added to the rollmean vector as the last value. This will ensure that the last entries of `z` in `sdf` are also returned (0.3 in the specific example).
- I use `transform` to add the `z` column to `bdf`
- `sapply(tb, function(x) which.max(x < m))` loops through the entries in `bdf$tb` and for each entry, computes the maximum index for which `bdf$tb` is less (earlier) than `m` (which holds the vector of rollmean entries). Only the maximum (latest) index is returned for each `bdf$tb` entry.
- That vector of indices is used in `sdf$y[sapply(tb, function(x) which.max(x < m))]` to extract the corresponding elements of `sdf$y` which will then be stored/copied to the new `z` column in `bdf`

Hope that helps

Comment: Using `rollmean` is pretty slick. Could be used to populate the `findInterval` vector in my method and side-step the problems I had with `difftime`.

Answer (score 3):

Edit note: I initially get a slightly different result than you did  which I now think was related to my lack of understanding of R difftime objects. Timezones in `POSIXt` objects also remain a mystery to me but I now see that when I coerced a 'difftime' object to 'numeric' that I got the value in "days".

The `findInterval` function is very useful as an index creation function that maps a values-vector where one has multiple adjoining non overlapping intervals. You really only have two time-points that split into three intervals.

```
bdf$z <- c(0.2,-0.1,0.3)[findInterval(bdf$tb, 
                c(-Inf, 
  sdf$ts[2] - 0.5*as.numeric(difftime(sdf$ts[2], sdf$ts[1], units="secs")), 
  sdf$ts[3] - 0.5*as.numeric(difftime(sdf$ts[3], sdf$ts[2],units="sec")), 
                 Inf))]

> bdf
                    tb    z
1  2013-05-19 17:11:22  0.2
2  2013-05-21 06:40:58  0.2
3  2013-05-22 20:10:34  0.2
4  2013-05-24 09:40:10 -0.1
5  2013-05-25 23:09:46 -0.1
6  2013-05-27 12:39:22  0.3
7  2013-05-29 02:08:58  0.3
8  2013-05-30 15:38:34  0.3
9  2013-06-01 05:08:10  0.3
10 2013-06-02 18:37:46  0.3
```

I also checked to see if my result would be affected by whether the intervals in findIntervals were closed on their right rather than the left (default) and saw no difference.