# Summarize the self-join index while avoiding cartesian product in R data.table

Tags: r, data.table, self-join, cross-join

With a 2-column `data.table`, I'd like to summarize the pairwise relationships in column 1 by summing the number of shared elements in column 2. In other words, how many shared Y elements does each pairwise combination of X-values have?

For example, I can do this in a 2-step process, first doing a cartesian cross join, then summarizing it like so:

```
d = data.table(X=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4), Y=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,5,6,4,5))
setkey(d, Y)
d2 = d[d, allow.cartesian=TRUE]
d2[, .N, by=c("X", "i.X")]
 #  X i.X N
 #1: 1   1 3
 #2: 2   1 3
 #3: 3   1 1
 #4: 1   2 3
 #5: 2   2 4
 #6: 3   2 1
 #7: 1   3 1
 #8: 2   3 1
 #9: 3   3 3
#10: 4   2 1
#11: 2   4 1
#12: 4   4 2
#13: 4   3 1
#14: 3   4 1
```

The second row of this result indicates, that `X=1` shares 3 Y-values with `X=2`; while `X=3` shares only 1 y-value with `X=4`.

Is there any way to do this while bypassing the cartesian join step, which leads to large inefficient tables? I want to do something like this on a table with millions of rows, and the cartesian join runs into the `2^31` vector size limit (in addition to becoming slow).

I'm imagining something like this:

```
d[d, list(X, length(Y)), by=c("X", "i.X")]
```

But this gives the error `i.X not found`

I can do this in SQL with the code below -- but just can't figure out how to translate this into data.table syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE test (X integer, Y integer);
INSERT INTO test VALUES(1, 1);
INSERT INTO test VALUES(1, 2);
INSERT INTO test VALUES(1, 3);
INSERT INTO test VALUES(2, 1);
INSERT INTO test VALUES(2, 2);
INSERT INTO test VALUES(2, 3);
INSERT INTO test VALUES(2, 4);
INSERT INTO test VALUES(3, 1);
INSERT INTO test VALUES(3, 5);
INSERT INTO test VALUES(3, 6);
INSERT INTO test VALUES(4, 4);
INSERT INTO test VALUES(4, 5);

SELECT A.X, B.X, COUNT(A.Y) as N FROM test as A JOIN test as B WHERE A.Y==B.Y GROUP BY A.X, B.X;
```

The point is that the column I want to summarize is the same as the column I am joining on. This question is similar to these, but not exactly:

[R Data.Table Join on Conditionals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28748046/r-data-table-join-on-conditionals)

[How to self join a data.table on a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14983805/how-to-self-join-a-data-table-on-a-condition)

The key difference being that I want to **summarize the index column**, which seems impossible to do with by=.EACHI.

Comment: what does your actual data look like - how many unique `X`'s and `Y`'s do you have?

Comment: @eddi -- well, for the large cases (where the cartesian join becomes a problem), it's on the order of 3,000 unique Ys, and 3,000 unique Xs, with about 2 million rows in the table _d_ (combinations of X/Y).

Answer (score 4):

If you can split your `Y`'s into groups that don't have a large intersection of `X`'s, you could do the computation by those groups first, resulting in a smaller intermediate table:

```
d[, grp := Y <= 3] # this particular split works best for OP data
d[, .SD[.SD, allow = T][, .N, by = .(X, i.X)], by = grp][,
    .(N = sum(N)), by = .(X, i.X)]
```

The intermediate table above has only 16 rows, as opposed to 26. Unfortunately I can't think of an easy way to create such grouping automatically.

Comment: Wow, there's some syntax for me to try to figure out -- thanks. I'd rather avoid the intermediate table completely if possible, but I'll look into this.

Comment: @sheffien I just did the exact same thing you did, but per `grp` first, and then summed the results (`.SD` is the piece of the original `data.table` corresponding to each `grp`).

Answer (score 2):

How about this one using `foverlaps()`. The more consecutive values of `Y` you've for each `X`, the lesser number of rows this'll produce compared to a cartesian join.

```
d = data.table(X=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4), Y=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,5,6,4,5))
setorder(d, X)
d[, id := cumsum(c(0L, diff(Y)) != 1L), by=X]
dd = d[, .(start=Y[1L], end=Y[.N]), by=.(X,id)][, id := NULL][]

ans <- foverlaps(dd, setkey(dd, start, end))
ans[, count := pmin(abs(i.end-start+1L), abs(end-i.start+1L), 
                    abs(i.end-i.start+1L), abs(end-start+1L))]
ans[, .(count = sum(count)), by=.(X, i.X)][order(i.X, X)]
#     X i.X count
#  1: 1   1     3
#  2: 2   1     3
#  3: 3   1     1
#  4: 1   2     3
#  5: 2   2     4
#  6: 3   2     1
#  7: 4   2     1
#  8: 1   3     1
#  9: 2   3     1
# 10: 3   3     3
# 11: 4   3     1
# 12: 2   4     1
# 13: 3   4     1
# 14: 4   4     2
```

> Note: make sure `X` and `Y` are integers for faster results. This is because joins on integer types are faster than on double types (`foverlaps` performs binary joins internally).

You can make this more memory efficient by using `which=TRUE` in `foverlaps()` and using the indices to generate `count` in the next step.

Answer (score 1):

You already have solution written in SQL so I suggest R package [sqldf](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sqldf/index.html)

Here's code:

```
library(sqldf)

result <- sqldf("SELECT A.X, B.X, COUNT(A.Y) as N FROM test as A JOIN test as B WHERE A.Y==B.Y GROUP BY A.X, B.X")
```