# Odd behavior when joining with multiple conditions

Tags: r, join, data.table

In [answering this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32011937/2204410) about rolling joins with the `data.table` package, I've run into some odd behavior when using multiple conditions.

Considering the following datasets:

```
dt <- data.table(t_id = c(1,4,2,3,5), place = c("a","a","d","a","d"), num = c(5.1, 5.1, 6.2, 5.1, 6.2), key=c("place"))
dt_lu <- data.table(f_id = c(rep(1,4),rep(2,3)), place = c("a","b","c","d","a","d","a"), num = c(6,7,8,9,6,7,8), key=c("place"))
```

When I want to join `dt` with `dt_lu` where only those cases of `dt_lu` that have the same `place` and where `dt_lu$num` is higher than `dt$num` as follows:

```
dt_lu[dt, list(tid = i.t_id,
               tnum = i.num,
               fnum = num[i.num < num],
               fid = f_id),
      by = .EACHI]
```

I get the desired result:

```
    place tid tnum fnum fid
 1:     a   1  5.1    6   1
 2:     a   1  5.1    6   2
 3:     a   1  5.1    8   2
 4:     a   4  5.1    6   1
 5:     a   4  5.1    6   2
 6:     a   4  5.1    8   2
 7:     a   3  5.1    6   1
 8:     a   3  5.1    6   2
 9:     a   3  5.1    8   2
10:     d   2  6.2    9   1
11:     d   2  6.2    7   2
12:     d   5  6.2    9   1
13:     d   5  6.2    7   2
```

When I want to add an additional condition, I can get the desired result easily by chaining that additional conditions as follows:

```
dt_lu[dt, list(tid = i.t_id,
               tnum = i.num,
               fnum = num[i.num < num],
               fid = f_id),
      by = .EACHI][fnum - tnum < 2]
```

which gives me:

```
   place tid tnum fnum fid
1:     a   1  5.1    6   1
2:     a   1  5.1    6   2
3:     a   4  5.1    6   1
4:     a   4  5.1    6   2
5:     a   3  5.1    6   1
6:     a   3  5.1    6   2
7:     d   2  6.2    7   2
8:     d   5  6.2    7   2
```

However when I add the extra condition (i.e.: the difference has to be less than `2`) as follows:

```
dt_lu[dt, list(tid = i.t_id,
               tnum = i.num,
               fnum = num[i.num < num & num - i.num < 2],
               fid = f_id),
      by = .EACHI]
```

I do not get the expected result:

```
    place tid tnum fnum fid
 1:     a   1  5.1    6   1
 2:     a   1  5.1    6   2
 3:     a   1  5.1    6   2
 4:     a   4  5.1    6   1
 5:     a   4  5.1    6   2
 6:     a   4  5.1    6   2
 7:     a   3  5.1    6   1
 8:     a   3  5.1    6   2
 9:     a   3  5.1    6   2
10:     d   2  6.2    7   1
11:     d   2  6.2    7   2
12:     d   5  6.2    7   1
13:     d   5  6.2    7   2
```

Moreover, I get the following warning message:

> Warning message: In `[.data.table`(dt_lu, dt, list(tid = i.t_id, tnum
>   = i.num, fnum = num[i.num <  :   Column 3 of result for group 1 is length 2 but the longest column in this result is 3. Recycled leaving
>   remainder of 1 items. This warning is once only for the first group
>   with this issue.

The expected result would be:

```
    place tid tnum fnum fid
 1:     a   1  5.1    6   1
 2:     a   1  5.1    6   2
 4:     a   4  5.1    6   1
 5:     a   4  5.1    6   2
 7:     a   3  5.1    6   1
 8:     a   3  5.1    6   2
11:     d   2  6.2    7   2
13:     d   5  6.2    7   2
```

I deliberately kept the rownumbers from the first example to show which rows have to be maintained in the final result (which is the same as the working solution).

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28748046/r-data-table-join-on-conditionals/28748717#28748717) shows, it should be possible to use multiple conditions inside the join operation.

I tried the following alternatives, but both of them don't work:

```
dt_lu[dt, list(tid = i.t_id,
               tnum = i.num,
               fnum = num[(i.num < num) & (num - i.num < 2)],
               fid = f_id),
      by = .EACHI]

dt_lu[dt, {
  val = num[(i.num < num) & (num - i.num < 2)];
  list(tid = i.t_id,
       tnum = i.num,
       fnum = val,
       fid = f_id)},
  by = .EACHI]
```

Could someone explain me why I don't get the desired result with multiple conditions inside the join operation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The warning message gives away the issue. Also, using `print()` is quite helpful here.

```
dt_lu[dt, print(i.num < num & num - i.num < 2), by=.EACHI]
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
# [1] FALSE  TRUE
# [1] FALSE  TRUE
# Empty data.table (0 rows) of 3 cols: place,place,num
```

Consider the first case where the condition evaluates to `TRUE, TRUE, FALSE`. There are 3 observations for this group. And your `j-expression` contains:

```
.(tid = i.t_id,
  tnum = i.num,
  fnum = num[i.num < num & num - i.num < 2],
  fid = f_id)
```

`i.t_id` and `i.num` are of length 1 (as they come from `dt`). But `num[..condn..]` will return length = 2, whereas `f_id` will return length = 3. Both the length=1 and length=2 items will be recycled to the length of the longest item/vector = 3. That leads to incorrect result. Since 3 isn't perfectly divisible by 2, it returns the warning.

What you intend to do is:

```
.(tid = i.t_id,
  tnum = i.num,
  fnum = num[i.num < num & num - i.num < 2],
  fid = f_id[i.num < num & num - i.num < 2])
```

or equivalently:

```
{  
  idx = i.num < num & num - i.num < 2
  .(tid  = i.t_id, tnum = i.num, fnum = num[idx], fid  = f_id[idx])
}
```

Putting it together:

```
dt_lu[dt, 
       {
         idx = i.num < num & num - i.num < 2
        .(tid  = i.t_id, tnum = i.num, fnum = num[idx], fid  = f_id[idx])
       }, 
by = .EACHI]
#    place tid tnum fnum fid
# 1:     a   1  5.1    6   1
# 2:     a   1  5.1    6   2
# 3:     a   4  5.1    6   1
# 4:     a   4  5.1    6   2
# 5:     a   3  5.1    6   1
# 6:     a   3  5.1    6   2
# 7:     d   2  6.2    7   2
# 8:     d   5  6.2    7   2
```

Comment: Thanx! If interpret your anwer well, I was lucky when using only one condition because the number of observations is the same for both `fnum` and `fid`.