# Match and find the earliest value in R

Tags: r

I have two tables, say one is Sales History, the other is Key Clients.

The Sales History table looks like this(contains 500,000 rows):

```
Client No.   Transaction Date   Sales Amount
       abc          1/12/2014            100
       def          2/28/2014            200
       hij          3/01/2014            300
       abc          2/18/2014            400
       abc          5/26/2014            500
       xyz          7/15/2014            600
       def          8/23/2014            700
       hij          9/19/2014            800
```

And the Key Clients table looks like this:

```
Client No.
       abc
       def
       xyz
```

Now what I want to do with R is that, based on the Key Clients table, I need to create a new table matching the earliest Sales Amount from the Sales History table. The desired results looks like this:

```
Client No.  Earliest Sales Amount
       abc                    100
       def                    200
       xyz                    600
```

Answer (score 3):

If the 'Transaction Date' column is ordered, then we can use `match`

```
df2$EarliestSalesAmount <- df1[,3][match(df2[,1], df1[,1])]
```

Or we can use `data.table` to join both the datasets after setting the key as 'Client_No.'.  `order` using 'Transaction_Date' after converting to 'Date' class, select the first row (`.SD[1L]`) by 'Client_No', assign the unwanted columns to `NULL`, and change the column names accordingly (`setnames`)

```
library(data.table)
 res <- setkey(setDT(df1), Client_No.)[df2][order(as.Date(Transaction_Date, 
         format='%m/%d/%Y')),.SD[1L] ,Client_No.][, 2:= NULL]
 setnames(res, 2, 'Earliest_Sales_Amount')
#    Client_No. Earliest_Sales_Amount
#1:        abc                   100
#2:        def                   200
#3:        xyz                   600
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Client_No. = c("abc", "def", "hij", "abc", 
"abc", 
"xyz", "def", "hij"), Transaction_Date = c("1/12/2014", "2/28/2014", 
"3/01/2014", "2/18/2014", "5/26/2014", "7/15/2014", "8/23/2014", 
"9/19/2014"), Sales_Amount = c(100L, 200L, 300L, 400L, 500L, 
600L, 700L, 800L)), .Names = c("Client_No.", "Transaction_Date", 
"Sales_Amount"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

df2 <- structure(list(Client_No. = c("abc", "def", "xyz")),
.Names = "Client_No.", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 3):

I will also recommend using `data.table`s *binary join*, but I will utilize `.EACHI` for this

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(df)[, Transaction.Date := as.IDate(Transaction.Date, "%m/%d/%Y")], Client.No.)
df[key, .(Earliest.Sales.Amont = Sales.Amount[which.min(Transaction.Date)]), by = .EACHI]
#    Client.No. Earliest.Sales.Amont
# 1:        abc                  100
# 2:        def                  200
# 3:        xyz                  600
```

First, we will convert your data set (`df`) to a `data.table` class using `setDT`, convert `Transaction.Date` to a `Date` class so R will understand what you mean while looking for the *minimum date* and then key it by `Client.No.` in order to perform a *binary join* (this is very efficient for a big data set like yours). Then, while performing the *binary join* on the key table (`key`) we will use `by = .EACHI` in order to locate the `Sale.Amount` within the earliest date in the data set.

Comment: Excellent use of `by=.EACHI`. Only thing I'd add is to check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27004566/559784) for a detailed explanation of `by=.EACHI`, until the vignettes are done..

Answer (score 2):

How about, using 'dplyr', something like the following? (not tested, using some easier-to-type labels)

```
sal_hist_first <- sales_hist %>% 
  mutate(trans_date=as.Date(trans_date, format="%m/%d/%Y")) %>%
  group_by(client_no) %>%
  summarise(earliest_sales_amount = sales_amount[trans_date == min(trans_date)])

result <- keys_clients %>% left_join(sal_hist_first)
```

Comment: Wasn't clear what the format of the transaction date in the dataframe is, but agree code that converts in any case would be more robust

Answer (score 2):

To give a more detailed answer it would be useful to know the used programming language/IDE and exact database system.

But assuming you use something like MySQL, MSSQL or PostgreSQL and you are able to execute SQL statements the following should give you an idea what to do.

First of all you could open the Sales History Table orderd by the Transaction date. Then you could iterate through it to find the respective Key clients. 
Or if your Database allows the TOP statement you could use a kind of the following SQL Statement for each Key Client:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Client_No, Sales_Amount FROM tbl_sales_history WHERE Client_No = '<KEY CLIENT>' ORDER BY Transaction_Date
```

This SQL Statement would return the first record for a key client of all the records ordered by the transaction date. Which is of course the earliest sale.

In short key to you question is to order your sales history by the transaction date.

EDIT: Just saw that the programming language used is R. So my answer is probably not that useful for this example, but it should work as a general help.

Comment: Yeah, just saw this myself. Shame on me I did not recognize this myself earlier.

Comment: One can actually can use this answer in R using the `sqldf` package. So you can keep it (though I didn't check if this actually works).

Comment: Thank you for this information. As I know nothing about R, I was not sure if my answer is applicable or not.