# subset based on date in a reference table

Tags: r, data.table, subset, plyr

I have table1 as follows.

```
   StudentId        Date1         Lunch
   23433            2014-08-26    Yes
   233989           2014-08-18    No
   909978           2014-08-06    No
   777492           2014-08-11    Yes
   3987387          2014-08-26    No
```

I have another table, table2 which is as follows

```
Id  StudentId        Date2        Result_Nm
1   777492           2012.06.10   0.1
2   777492           2013.12.06   2.0
3   777492           2014.08.30   0.6
4   23433            2011.08.26   3.0
5   23433            2015.04.06   3.0
6   233989           2011.05.14   0.003
7   233989           2014.09.14   0.05
8   909978           2004-09-12   0.2
9   909978           2005-05-10   0.23
10  909978           2015-01-02   2.4
11  3987387          2014-10-06   3.5
12  3987387          2014-08-26   1.17
```

I want to retain only observations from table2 dataset where the Date2 values are less than the Date1 values for each StudentId. In other words it should contain these rows.

```
  Id  StudentId        Date2         Result_Nm
  1   777492           2012.06.10    0.1
  2   777492           2013.12.06    2.0
  4   23433            2011.08.26    3.0
  6   233989           2014.09.14    0.05
  8   909978           2004-09-12    0.2
  9   909978           2005-05-10    0.23
  12  3987387          2014-08-26    1.17
```

Observation 3 is excluded because the Date1 value for StudentId 777492 is 2014-08-11  and this value is less than 2014.08.30, similarly observations 5,7,10,11 so on. I have used subset before but this is little more challenging , need help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can change the 'Date' columns to 'Date' class by using `ymd` from `lubridate`.  It can take multiple formats (`.`, `-`).  Join the two dataset (`left_join`) by 'StudentId', remove the rows using `filter` and `select` the specific columns

```
library(lubridate) 
library(dplyr)
df2$Date2 <- ymd(df2$Date2)
df1$Date1 <- ymd(df1$Date1)

left_join(df2, df1, by='StudentId') %>% 
                     filter(Date2 <=Date1) %>% 
                     select(1:4)
#    Id StudentId      Date2 Result_Nm
#1  1    777492 2012-06-10     0.100
#2  2    777492 2013-12-06     2.000
#3  4     23433 2011-08-26     3.000
#4  6    233989 2011-05-14     0.003
#5  8    909978 2004-09-12     0.200
#6  9    909978 2005-05-10     0.230
#7 12   3987387 2014-08-26     1.170
```

Or we can use `data.table`.  Here we convert the  'df2' from 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT`), set the key as 'StudentId' (`setkey(..., StudentId)`), `join` with a subset of 'df1'  ('StudentId', 'Date1'), filter the output dataset based on the condition (`.SD[Date2 <= Date1]`) grouped by the 'key' variable.  More info about `.EACHI` is [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27004002/eachi-in-data-table)

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(df2),StudentId)[df1[1:2], .SD[Date2<=Date1],by=.EACHI][order(Id)]
#   StudentId Id      Date2 Result_Nm
#1:    777492  1 2012-06-10     0.100
#2:    777492  2 2013-12-06     2.000
#3:     23433  4 2011-08-26     3.000
#4:    233989  6 2011-05-14     0.003
#5:    909978  8 2004-09-12     0.200
#6:    909978  9 2005-05-10     0.230
#7:   3987387 12 2014-08-26     1.170
```

**NOTE:**  The 'Dates' were already changed to 'Date' class before the `join`.

#### data

```
df1 <-  structure(list(StudentId = c(23433L, 233989L, 909978L,
777492L, 
3987387L), Date1 = c("2014-08-26", "2014-08-18", "2014-08-06", 
"2014-08-11", "2014-08-26"), Lunch = c("Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", 
"No")), .Names = c("StudentId", "Date1", "Lunch"), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

df2 <-  structure(list(Id = 1:12, StudentId = c(777492L, 777492L, 
777492L, 
23433L, 23433L, 233989L, 233989L, 909978L, 909978L, 909978L, 
3987387L, 3987387L), Date2 = c("2012.06.10", "2013.12.06", 
"2014.08.30", 
"2011.08.26", "2015.04.06", "2011.05.14", "2014.09.14", "2004-09-12", 
"2005-05-10", "2015-01-02", "2014-10-06", "2014-08-26"), 
Result_Nm = c(0.1, 
2, 0.6, 3, 3, 0.003, 0.05, 0.2, 0.23, 2.4, 3.5, 1.17)),
.Names = c("Id", 
"StudentId", "Date2", "Result_Nm"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.

```
d1 <- read.table("d1.txt", header=T)
d2 <- read.table("d2.txt", header=T)
d3 <- merge(d1,d2, by="StudentId")
d3$Date1 <- strptime(d3$Date1, format="%Y-%m-%d")
library(stringr)
d3$Date2 <-str_c(str_sub(d3$Date2, 1L,4L),"-",str_sub(d3$Date2,6L,7L), "-", str_sub(d3$Date2,9L,10L))
d3$Date2 <- strptime(d3$Date2, format="%Y-%m-%d")
d3$mark <- d3$Date2-d3$Date1
d3 <- d3[d3$mark<1,]
d3 <- d3[,c(1,4,5,6)]
```