# Merge and assign by reference, `by` ID

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to define a new variable in a `data.table` through a merge. The wrinkle is that I'd like to access `.N` in order to define the new variable by group, so I'd like to use `by` as well, but this is causing an error.

MRE:

```
dt1<-data.table(pd=rep(1:2,each=3),rnk=rep(1:3,2),
                var=c(3:1,1:3),key="pd")
dt2<-data.table(pd=c(1,2),chk=c(2,2),key="pd")

dt1[dt2,new:=var[.N]>i.chk,by=pd]
```

As you can see, I'd like to define `new` to be `TRUE` whenever the (within-`pd`) highest-`rnk` value of `var` exceeds 2. The code above seems natural enough to me, but this results in an error: `object 'i.chk' not found` (suggesting the merge has not been completed, as the name space of `dt2` appears unavailable).

I can get around this with a second step:

```
> dt1[dt2,new:=var>i.chk][,new:=new[.N],by=pd][]
   pd rnk var   new
1:  1   1   3 FALSE
2:  1   2   2 FALSE
3:  1   3   1 FALSE
4:  2   1   1  TRUE
5:  2   2   2  TRUE
6:  2   3   3  TRUE
```

However, this slows down my code substantially since I'm using `` `:=` `` to update around 6 such columns.

Is there no way to update by reference by group when merging?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `.EACHI`

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+ 
dt1[dt2, new:=var[.N]>i.chk,.EACHI][]
#   pd rnk var   new
#1:  1   1   3 FALSE
#2:  1   2   2 FALSE
#3:  1   3   1 FALSE
#4:  2   1   1  TRUE
#5:  2   2   2  TRUE
#6:  2   3   3  TRUE
```

See `?data.table` and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27004002/eachi-in-data-table/27004566#27004566) SO question linked therein:

> When `i` is a `data.table`, `DT[i,j,by=.EACHI]` evaluates `j` for the groups in `DT` that each row in `i` joins to. That is, you can join (in `i`) and aggregate (in `j`) simultaneously. We call this grouping by each `i`.

Also with the devel version of `data.table`, you may not need to set the key, but can use `on`.

```
 dt1[dt2, new:=var[.N] > i.chk ,on='pd', by =.EACHI][]
 #  pd rnk var   new
 #1:  1   1   3 FALSE
 #2:  1   2   2 FALSE
 #3:  1   3   1 FALSE
 #4:  2   1   1  TRUE
 #5:  2   2   2  TRUE
 #6:  2   3   3  TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks, my first time needing `.EACHI` in the field, now it's all making sense.