# Rcpp function inside data.table join

Tags: r, data.table, rcpp

### Question

Why does my `Rcpp` function inside a `data.table` join produce a different (& incorrect) result compared to when used outside of a join?

### Example

I have two `data.table`s, and I want to find the Euclidean distance between each pair of coordinates across both tables.

To do the distance calculation I've defined two functions, one in base R, and the other using `Rcpp`.

```
library(Rcpp)
library(data.table)

rEucDist <- function(x1, y1, x2, y2) return(sqrt((x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2))

cppFunction('NumericVector cppEucDistance(NumericVector x1, NumericVector y1,
                                          NumericVector x2, NumericVector y2){

            int n = x1.size();
            NumericVector distance(n);

            for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
              distance[i] = sqrt(pow((x2[i] - x1[i]), 2) + pow((y2[i] - y1[i]), 2));
            }
            return distance;
}')


dt1 <- data.table(id = rep(1, 6),
                  seq1 = 1:6,
                  x = c(1:6),
                  y = c(1:6))

dt2 <- data.table(id = rep(1, 6),
                  seq2 = 7:12,
                  x = c(6:1),
                  y = c(6:1))
```

When doing a join first, then calculating the distance, both functions produce the same result

```
dt_cpp <- dt1[ dt2, on = "id", allow.cartesian = T]
dt_cpp[, dist := cppEucDistance(x, y, i.x, i.y)]

dt_r <- dt1[ dt2, on = "id", allow.cartesian = T]
dt_r[, dist := rEucDist(x, y, i.x, i.y)]

all.equal(dt_cpp$dist, dt_r$dist)
# [1] TRUE
```

However, if I do the calculation within a join the results differ; the cpp version is incorrect.

```
dt_cppJoin <- dt1[
    dt2,
    { (cppEucDistance(x, y, i.x, i.y)) },
    on = "id",
    by = .EACHI
    ]

dt_rJoin <- dt1[
    dt2,
    { (rEucDist(x, y, i.x, i.y)) },
    on = "id",
    by = .EACHI
    ]

all.equal(dt_cppJoin$V1, dt_rJoin$V1)
# "Mean relative difference: 0.6173913"

## note that the R version of the join is correct
all.equal(dt_r$dist, dt_rJoin$V1)
# [1] TRUE
```

What is it about the `Rcpp` implementation that causes the join version to give a different result?

Comment: This might be relevant: `dt1[
    dt2,
    list(len1 = length(x), len2 = length(i.x)),
    on = "id",
    by=.EACHI
]` -- the allow.cartesian probably matters (though I haven't looked closely at your functions).

Comment: @Frank -  so it seems : `dt1[ dt2, list(len1 = length(x), len2 = length(i.x)), on = "id", allow.cartesian = T ]` - The trouble is, I'm trying to avoid the cartesian join as I don't have enough RAM.

Comment: I'm not sure how/where the symbols inside those function calls are evaluated, but have you tried printing from your R and Rcpp function their inputs? E.g. printing "x2" from both functions shows different vectors having been passed (the lengths seem to differ).

Comment: @alexis_laz - good observation - I'll explore this line of enquiry further

Comment: yes; it's certainly to do with the different vector sizes and the loop. The `EACHI` is reducing the `dt2` to 1-length vectors, so my loop in the `Rcpp` code is incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### tl;dr

1. Ultimately, this comes down to my lack of understanding of how `EACHI` works.
2. My C++ loop as it stands is relying on `x1` and `x2` being the same length. This is not the case when `EACHI` is used, so my vector-subsetting in the C++ function won't be correct. Therefore I'll need a more sophisticated C++ function.

---

I believe the 'issue' I'm seeing comes down to what `EACHI` is doing. After re-reading [Arun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27004566/5977215) again and again I think I understand it.

In particular, `EACHI` "evaluates j-expression on the matching rows for each row in Y". So it's taking the `Y` table (`dt2` in my case) and evaluating it each row at a time. This can be seen if you use a few `prints` inside the Rcpp function

```
## I'm reducing the data sets so the 'prints' are readible
dt1 <- data.table(id = rep(1, 2),
                  seq1 = 1:2,
                  x = c(1:2),
                  y = c(1:2))

dt2 <- data.table(id = rep(1, 2),
                  seq2 = 7:8,
                  x = c(6:5),
                  y = c(6:5))

cppFunction('NumericVector cppEucDistance(NumericVector x1, NumericVector y1,
                                          NumericVector x2, NumericVector y2){

  int n = x1.size();
  NumericVector distance(n);

  Rcpp::Rcout << "x1 size: " << x1.size() << std::endl;
  Rcpp::Rcout << "x2 size: " << x2.size() << std::endl;
  Rcpp::Rcout << "n size: " << n << std::endl;

  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    distance[i] = sqrt(pow((x2[i] - x1[i]), 2) + pow((y2[i] - y1[i]), 2));
  }
  return distance;
}')

dt_cppJoin <- dt1[
  dt2,
  {print(i.x); (cppEucDistance(x, y, i.x, i.y)) },
  on = "id",
  by = .EACHI
  ]
# [1] 6
# x1 size: 2
# x2 size: 1
# n size: 2
# [1] 5
# x1 size: 2
# x2 size: 1
# n size: 2
```

Notice in the output of the print statement that `x2` is only length 1 each iteration. Whereas `n` is 2. So my `x2[i]` will obviously 'fail' when `i` gets to the second element (remembering that C++ arrays are 0-indexed)

Whereas taking out the `EACHI` has the same effect as the full-join approach

```
dt_cppJoin <- dt1[
  dt2,
  {print(i.x); (cppEucDistance(x, y, i.x, i.y)) },
  on = "id"
  ]
# [1] 6 6 5 5
# x1 size: 4
# x2 size: 4
# n size: 4
```

---