# Sum of values greater than or equal too for each element in grouped dataframe (dplyr) R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a relatively large dataframe (~2,000,000 rows) where, for each row, I need to, within that observation's group, calculate the sum of every value greater than or equal to the current row's value.

Here is a sample data frame:

```
sample_df = data.frame(
  group_id = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
  value = c(10,12,14,12,8,8,21,10)
)
```

I currently have a very slow solution to do this using a loop and some filtering, however, having a faster solution would be much preferred. I've been trying to use dplyr however, I can not figure out how I can get the sum of the other observations after the data are grouped.

With the above toy example, here would be the desired output:

```
desired_output = data.frame(
  group_id = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
  value = c(10,12,14,12,8,8,21,10),
  output = c(38,26,0,26,39,39,0,21)
)
```

Looking around for solutions to this that have already been posted, I haven't seen a clear answer which explains how one can compare each observation in a group to the other observations, filtered on some criteria, in that group. I'd prefer a dplyr-based solution but if there are efficient base-R or data.table solutions than I'd be equally grateful!

Comment: How come value 12 in group 1 gives you an output of 24? I would expect 26

Comment: I am curious to see the data.table solution!!

Comment: ...Because I just messed up 2nd grade math when creating my output :(. Apologies for that mistake!

Comment: I permitted myself to edit it ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `tidyverse`. The trick is to use `map_dbl` to loop on every `value`.

```
library(tidyverse)
sample_df %>%
  group_by(group_id) %>%
  mutate(output= map_dbl(value,~sum(value[value>=.x]))-value) %>%
  ungroup

# A tibble: 8 x 3
  group_id value output
     <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1        1    10     38
2        1    12     26
3        1    14      0
4        1    12     26
5        2     8     39
6        2     8     39
7        2    21      0
8        2    10     21
```

`value` in the mutate line is your `value` 'subcolumn' (the group), while `.x` is its element you're looping on.

**a base solution**

```
within(sample_df,output <- unlist(tapply(
  value,group_id,function(x) sapply(x,function(y) sum(x[x>=y])-y))))
#   group_id value output
# 1        1    10     38
# 2        1    12     26
# 3        1    14      0
# 4        1    12     26
# 5        2     8     39
# 6        2     8     39
# 7        2    21      0
# 8        2    10     21
```

Comment: This is an incredibly elegant solution. If you don't mind me asking, what is "value" within the map_dbl function? Is it a tidyverse key phrase?

Edit: Nevermind, I spaced on my toy examples variables names.

Comment: This could be very slow for a 10^6 rows data frame no?

Comment: Value is your variable from your data set I think

Comment: As Max Ft says :). I updated with a small explanation, tell me if it's still confusing.

Answer (score 9):

Less compact and a little tricky but way faster and using only `data.table`.

The trick is that once your data is sorted in descending order by value for each `group_id` all you need to compute is a cumulative sum by `group_id` which is very fast.

Whenever a `value` appears multiple times within a group you want to keep the last cumulative sum which had taken into account all previous occurrences.

```
library(data.table)
DT=as.data.table(sample_df)[order(group_id,-value),]
DT[,output:=cumsum(value)-value,keyby=.(group_id)]
temp=DT[, .SD[.N], by=.(group_id,value)]  # Keep the last row by group and value
DT=merge(setDF(sample_df)[,.(group_id,value)],temp,by=c("group_id","value"),sort=F) 

#    group_id value output
# 1:        1    10     38
# 2:        1    12     26
# 3:        1    12     26
# 4:        1    14      0
# 5:        2     8     39
# 6:        2     8     39
# 7:        2    10     21
# 8:        2    21      0
```

This solution is `4000` times faster than the alternatives solutions proposed for the `10^6` observations benchmark. It works for up to `10^8` observations in less than a minute.

```
#       N data.table.trick             dplyr          sapply              base
#1: 1e+06 0.067678928 secs 261.32966185 secs 282.639625 secs 275.08949995 secs
#2: 1e+05 0.013036013 secs   3.55517507 secs   5.356922 secs   3.36490607 secs
#3: 1e+04 0.007019043 secs   0.09926391 secs   0.312326 secs   0.04562092 secs
```

I computed the time with `sys.Time()` using the following benchmark:

```
N=10^8 # observation
G=20 # group
V=100 # values
sample_df = data.table(
  group_id = sample(1:G,N,replace=T),
  value = sample(1:V,V,replace=T)
)
```

Comment: nice trick to use the `cumsum` ! can you maybe include your benchmark ?

Comment: worth mentionning also that you're losing the row order, it may be important for OP.

Comment: I will edit my answer. By benchmark do you mean the simulated dataset I used to perform the time comparison?

Comment: Yes, the reproducible comparison, on `SO` `microbenchmark` is often used, you'll find a lot of them if you look it up in the search tool.

Comment: This will preserve your row order: `merge(setDF(sample_df)[,.(group_id,value)],temp,by=c("group_id","value"),sort=F)`

Comment: I did not think about preserving the row order. Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

Using R base `*apply` functions. Not as readable as @Moody_Mudskipper answer, but same output without any extra package.

```
sample_df$output <- unlist(lapply(split(sample_df, sample_df$group_id), function(x){
  sapply(1:nrow(x), function(i){
    sum(x$value[x$value >= x$value[i]])-x$value[i];
  })
}))

sample_df

  group_id value output
1        1    10     38
2        1    12     26
3        1    14      0
4        1    12     26
5        2     8     39
6        2     8     39
7        2    21      0
8        2    10     21
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a simple non-equi join problem:

```
library(data.table)
dt = as.data.table(sample_df)

dt[dt, on = .(group_id, value >= value), by = .EACHI,
   .(output = sum(x.value) - i.value)]
#   group_id value output
#1:        1    10     38
#2:        1    12     26
#3:        1    14      0
#4:        1    12     26
#5:        2     8     39
#6:        2     8     39
#7:        2    21      0
#8:        2    10     21
```

Comment: great solution! This will help some: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27004002/eachi-in-data-table