# Looking up data in another data.table from j

Tags: r, function, input, data.table, lookup

I have been running into a computation time issue when working with large datasets and applying functions that use multiple columns of the data.table as inputs. Here is a simplified example:

```
require(data.table)
main_dt   <- data.table(Start=(1:2), End=c(2,2))
lookup_dt <- data.table(Year = 1:3, Amount = c(10,20,30))
```

So:

```
> main_dt
Start End
1:     1   2
2:     2   2
```

And

```
> lookup_dt
   Year Amount
1:    1     10
2:    2     20
3:    3     30
```

What I want is to add a column in data.table **main_dt** that includes the sum of Amounts of Years between *Start* and *End*. So something like this, but there is a referencing error.

```
main_dt[, Amount := lookup_dt[ Year >= start & Year <= end, sum(Amount)]]
Warning messages:
1: In Year >= Start :  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In Year <= End :  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

If the Amount would depend only on one variable, I could do:

```
main_dt[, GreaterAmount := lapply(Start, function(x) return (lookup_dt[Year >= x, sum(Amount)]))]
```

to get:

```
> main_dt
Start End Amount GreaterAmount
1:     1   2     30            60
2:     2   2     30            50
```

Which would be ok, but

- I need to apply a function that actually depends on both *Start* **and** *End*
- Applying a function for every row individually slows down computation process rapidly. A vectorized solution would be highly appreciated.

Looking forward to any suggestions!

Thank you!
Markus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the join columns should be the same class, so we can either convert `main_dt$End` to integer, or `main_df$Start` and `lookup_dt$Year` to numeric. I'll choose the first:

```r
main_dt[, End := as.integer(End)]
main_dt
#    Start   End
#    <int> <int>
# 1:     1     2
# 2:     2     2
```

From here, we can do a joining-assignment:

```r
main_dt[, Amount := lookup_dt[.SD, sum(Amount), on = .(Year >= Start, Year <= End), by = .EACHI]$V1 ]
main_dt
#    Start   End Amount
#    <int> <int>  <num>
# 1:     1     2     30
# 2:     2     2     20
```

If you're somewhat familiar with `data.table`, note that `.SD` referenced is actually the contents of `main_dt`, so `lookup_dt[.SD,...]` is effectively *"main_dt left join lookup_dt"*. From there, the `on=` should be normal, and `sum(Amount)` is what you want to aggregate. The only new thing introduced here is the use of `by=.EACHI`, which can be confusing; some links for that:

- https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/reference/special-symbols.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/27004566/3358272

Comment: Thank you, this helped me to understand the merging and referencing concepts more deeply!