Changing a variable based on a subsequent variable
I want to reformat my data so that if a person has a subsequent negative test after a positive, that positive test is altered to negative (it is regarded as a false positive).
Within my data set a positive test is denoted by either equivocal, indeterminate or positive in the test column.
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

date=c("2023-01-01", "2023-02-07", "2023-02-20","2023-01-01", "2023-02-07", "2023-02-20", "2023-01-01", "2023-05-10", "2023-01-01", "2023-01-01", "2023-01-01", "2023-01-01", "2023-01-01", "2023-01-01", "2023-01-10", "2023-01-01", "2023-01-10")
ID=c("A", "A", "A","A2", "A2", "A2", "B", "B", "C", "D", "D", "D1", "D1", "E", "E", "F", "F")
test=c("negative", "equivocal", "negative", "negative", "indeterminate", "negative", "negative", "negative", "positive", "positive", "negative","indeterminate", "negative", "positive", "negative", "negative", "positive")
df=as.data.table(cbind(date, ID, test))  
df[, date := as.Date(date)] 

So the following highlighted tests would all be converted to negative due to there being a negative test on the same day or after the positive.


df[, test2 := df[.SD, 
                 on = .(ID, date >= date), 
                 if (any(test == "negative")) "negative" else NA_character_, 
                 by = .EACHI]$V1 |> 
              fcoalesce(test)]

#           date     ID          test    test2
#         <Date> <char>        <char>   <char>
#  1: 2023-01-01      A      negative negative
#  2: 2023-02-07      A     equivocal negative
#  3: 2023-02-20      A      negative negative
#  4: 2023-01-01     A2      negative negative
#  5: 2023-02-07     A2 indeterminate negative
#  6: 2023-02-20     A2      negative negative
#  7: 2023-01-01      B      negative negative
#  8: 2023-05-10      B      negative negative
#  9: 2023-01-01      C      positive positive
# 10: 2023-01-01      D      positive negative
# 11: 2023-01-01      D      negative negative
# 12: 2023-01-01     D1 indeterminate negative
# 13: 2023-01-01     D1      negative negative
# 14: 2023-01-01      E      positive negative
# 15: 2023-01-10      E      negative negative
# 16: 2023-01-01      F      negative negative
# 17: 2023-01-10      F      positive positive


Thanks for your comment. I have tried this and am getting the following error: Error in [.data.table(sent_hiv, , :=(HIV_final, sent_hiv[.SD, on = .(DUPE_SAMPLE,  :
Supplied 484610 items to be assigned to 482347 items of column 'HIV_final'. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() to make this intent clear to readers of your code.

sent_hiv[, HIV_final := sent_hiv[.SD,
on = .(DUPE_SAMPLE, DateTest >= DateTest),
if (any(HIV_cleaned == "negative")) "negative" else HIV_cleaned,
by = .EACHI]$V1]

@VickiLatham Thanks for feedback. I can see why and made an update.

Thanks. Would you be able to explain to me what this part of the code does: by = .EACHI]$V1 |>
fcoalesce(test)

If there is a same day / future negative test we replace the row by negative else NA. fcoalesce then fills in the NAs with the corresponding row from the original test. Regarding .EACHI it basically says do it row by row instead of by group. There is more in-depth explanation here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27004002/eachi-in-data-table
